# How does this OCaml code work?

Tags: ocaml

The following OCaml code creates a universal type (not mine, from [Jane Street's website](https://blogs.janestreet.com/a-universal-type/)):

```
module Univ : sig
   type t 
   val embed: unit -> ('a -> t) * (t -> 'a option) 
end = struct
   type t = bool -> unit
   let embed () =
    let r = ref None in
    let put x =
     let sx = Some x in
     fun b -> r := if b then sx else None
    in
    let get f =
     f true;
     let res = !r in
     f false; res
    in
    put, get
end
```

creates a universal type. In it, a call to `embed ()` creates a 2-tuple of functions. The first function in the tuple stores an arbitrary value in the closed-over ref cell; the second function retrieves it. If the wrong value of type t is given to the second function, it returns `None` instead. However, it appears to me that this would cause the ref cell to be cleared and thus further attempts to retrieve the value to fail, which does not happen. Also, I do not understand in general what happens when passed a wrong value to the projection function get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `embed` is called, a fresh reference `r` and two fresh closures for the functions `put` and `get` are allocated. When some `put` is called it returns a fresh function (let's call it the setter) that also has `r` in its closure.

- If that setter is given to the corresponding `get`, the `r` captured in both closure is the same, hence when `get` calls `f true`, it modifies the `r` in `get` closure, and `let res = !r` read a `Some` value.

  ```
  let get f =
    f true;         (* assign the shared reference r *)
    let res = !r in (* read   r *)
    f false;        (* clear  r *)
    res
  ```
- If the setter is given to a non-corresponding `get`, the `r` captured by `get` and the setter is not the same. (let's call them `r1` and `r2`)

  ```
  let get f =
    f true;         (* assign r1 *)
    let res = !r in (* read   r2 *)
    f false;        (* clear  r1 *)
    res
  ```

  Since the get takes care of always clearing `r`, we know that before calling
  `get`, `r2` is `None`. Hence `get` will return `None`.

Comment: Ah I see. `r` always holds  `None` initially so it cannot be tricked into giving a wrong value. That also explains the lack of thread-safety.

Comment: Another kind of thread safe approach would be to use a shared exception. This is the last answer by Alain Frisch on the post you link.